# Are multiple lets in a guard statement the same as a single let?

Tags: swift, swift3, guard

Is there any functional difference between:

```
guard let foo = bar, let qux = taco else { 
  ...
}
```

And:

```
guard let foo = bar, qux = taco else {
  ...
}
```

It seems to me they're the same and the extra `let` is not required?

Comment: The second variant was allowed in Swift 2, but isn't anymore in Swift 3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These are different in Swift 3. In this case:

```
guard let foo = bar, let qux = taco else {
```

you're saying "optional-unwrap bar into foo. If successful, optional unwrap taco into qux. If successful continue. Else ..."

On the other hand this:

```
guard let foo = bar, qux = taco else {
```

says "optional-unwrap bar into foo. As a Boolean, evaluate the assignement statement `qux = taco`" Since assignment statements do not return Booleans in Swift, this is a syntax error.

This change allows much more flexible `guard` statements, since you can intermix optional unwrapping and Booleans throughout the chain. In Swift 2.2 you had to unwrap everything and then do all Boolean checks at the end in the `where` clause (which sometimes made it impossible to express the condition).

Comment: Okay, good to know.  Obviously I'm still on swift 2.  I have a linter that is complaining about the first syntax that is going to need some changing when we upgrade.  Thanks!

Comment: Xcode 8 itself will periodically display an error for this if you're working with Swift 2.3, then it goes away on some final pass the compiler makes.

Answer (score 7):

No it´s not the same anymore in Swift 3.0. Xcode gives you an error and asks you to add `let` when you´re applying multiple variables.

[image]

So you should use

```
guard let foo = bar, let qux = taco else { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: same in Swift 4 too, must need a 'let' for every guard check !